# Reading unicode characters in sessions with wlatin1 encoding in SAS

Tags: sql-server, unicode, encoding, utf-8, sas

I have a library which connects to a SQL Server 2012 instance.   One of the registered tables contains international addresses so can contain non-Latin characters (Chinese, Russian etc) in `nvarchar` columns.  When connecting to the table via Enterprise Guide, the non-Latin characters are missing.

I have tried changing the SAS Foundation `sasv9.cfg` to point at the u8 nls folder which has a default encoding of `utf-8` instead of the en folder, which is `wlatin1`.

However, my users then complain their datasets written with the `wlatin1` encoding are inaccessible.  Changing the `sasv9.cfg` file back to the 'en' nls folder resolves the issue.

Is there a way I can get users to game this by starting their individual sessions as `utf-8?`

Thanks

Comment: Why would users be unable to read a WLATIN1 dataset in a u8 session?  That seems wrong to me.  SAS may be able to help there.

Comment: Are you using EG with local SAS or connecting to a server? You can have your SAS admin setup two app servers using different encodings.

Comment: @Joe - there are definitely issues with wlatin1 to utf8 conversions, am experiencing them in my current project..

Comment: @Tom's suggestion is a good one

Answer (score 3):

You have a few approaches available. One is to use the `inencoding=utf8` [library option](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=nlsref&docsetVersion=3.1&docsetTarget=n02q3gv9mfdwnmn1ca9kqa3gbayl.htm&locale=en).

If this fails, you could then try using the `encoding=utf8` [dataset option](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0kzmrsdx5evkxn1ihs24h8ljg2b.htm).

As a last resort, you can use the `kcvt` [function](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=nlsref&docsetTarget=p1b70e0jx70qtyn1txiolu9txijf.htm&docsetVersion=3.2&locale=en) to translate the specific variable, eg :

```
kcvt(YourVariable,'utf8','wlatin1')
```

You can't modify the encoding of workspace session without updating the config file, although it is possible to 'game' a stored process session by setting the context of your client - see the [locale gotcha](https://www.rawsas.com/2016/12/look-out-locale-gotcha/).

Comment: +1 for the options.  Unfortunately still no joy, so I figure it must be the default encoding in the config file for the sessions or bust.  I'll get in touch with SAS on it.

Comment: another thing to try - increase the length of your variables before doing the transcoding.  Some double byte chars will take more space in your (previously) single byte encoding.